# Is is possible to serialize fields (not just properties) with CsvHelper?

Tags: .net, csvhelper

I'm using [CsvHelper](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) but I'd like to be able to serialize fields and not just properties.  Is there a way to do this?

Note that this is hard to search for, because the documentation uses the word "Field" to mean a class property, but I'm talking about an actual class field, that is, `MyIntField` in this class:

```
class Something
{
    public int MyIntProperty {get; set;}
    public int MyIntField;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not currently possible. You get an error message

`'MyIntField' is not a property. Did you try to map a field by accident?`

Comment: What if you want to map a field on purpose? I find that I have a lot of simple classes that historically didn't need any kind of serialization, and it was easier to define these as fields, because it's a little less typing. But now that I do want to serialize them, `CsvHelper` can't see them. I could easily go back and make them all properties, but this is a little tedious, especially since I don't get compiler errors, only runtime errors.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to have a lambda expression constraint like there is with generic types. That would be really nice though. With auto properties you could just add the `{ get; set; }` to the end of each field to make it a property. If you would like a config option to have it look at fields also, add an issue to the github project. The reason it isn't there is because it's good practice to use a property instead of a field. In generally, people don't want their fields used.

Comment: I'll have to think about whether I want to migrate to properties, or stick with fields.  I think if you just want a public piece of data with no logic other than get and set, a field is pretty convenient, and I like using them.  But adding the extra characters isn't a big deal either.

Comment: Would you reconsider adding support for fields? Although it's preferable to use properties in these cases, it doesn't help when existing tools or libraries use fields (e.g., LINQPad and its SQL entities).  A wrapper class would have to be created and can be troublesome when there are many columns and tables to map.  That's a lot of work when it should be trivial to allow it.

Comment: Yes. It's a feature request that will done. https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/416